# Feeds node import does not seem to call appropriate hooks to clear page from cache

Tags: feeds, caching, nodes

I use Feeds for node import, but this does not refresh page content for anonymous users on my site.

Are there some hooks not being called by Feeds on node creation that should flag the page as dirty in the cache?

Feeds creates some node content hourly. The D7 site has a (home) Page containing a Block with a View of this content. There is some basic caching enabled on the site (Cache pages for anonymous users, Cache blocks, Minimum cache lifetime - none, Expiration of cached pages - none). I'm also using Memcache which should be transparent.

When I create new content or even edit existing content by hand that would show within this View, then the Page containing the Block updates for both registered and anonymous users.
But if I use Feeds to create this same new node content, then the page never updates after new content node is created.
If I clear all caches by hand, then of course the new content will show up within the page.